# is there a method to execute a function after a spesific condition in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

for exemple I have a user model like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
     const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
     username: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          },
      Points: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0,
          },
module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

then I want to execute a function automatically when user.points is equal to 10 with express js, is there any solution ?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please provide more details.

Comment: How are you trying to achieve user.points? Is there any code you missed out in the question above?

Comment: yes my bad, so in my application there's many routes responsible for the points update with adding +2,+3... I just want to know if there's is a solution responsible to execute a function when points are equal to 10

Comment: You can trigger a polling function which can check for the value of points and when it is equal to 10, you can do your logic. You can call that function 1. wherever you are updating the value of points or 2. Call you function with timegap of every 1 minute after start of your application till points is equal to 10

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, do you have a little exemple of how this trigger work?

Comment: There goes your sample code that I came up with. Try it out and viola if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yessine, may you should try something like this. You can add checkForPoints wherever you are updating the Points and proceed with your things,

```
const { Users } = require('/schema.js');

const checkForPoints = async (username) => {
    await Users.findOne({ username }, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log("enter error ------", err)
        }

        if (data && data.Points === 10) {
            // Execute your code
        }
    });
};

// Users schema(schema.js)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('your db', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const requestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    Points: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', requestSchema);
```

Polling is a technique where we check for fresh data over a given interval by periodically making API requests to a server.enables you to periodically check for the newest values of data and do further requests once it enters the desired state.

Comment: Thank you very much @Owner, that really helped me.